Does little endian impact arrays?
given the following command in C language:
unsigned char myID[10] = "123456789"
And given the fact I'm using little endianness with x86 architecture, how would that be saved in memory?
is it:
Address     | Value
----------------------
0x10b       | 0x00   ('\0')
0x10a       | 0x00   ('\0')
0x109       | 0x00   ('\0')
0x108       | 0x39   ('9')

0x107       | 0x38   ('8')
0x106       | 0x37   ('7')
0x105       | 0x36   ('6')
0x104       | 0x35   ('5')

0x103       | 0x34   ('4')
0x102       | 0x33   ('3')
0x101       | 0x32   ('2')
0x100       | 0x31   ('1')

or the opposite way around? I know that in little endianness given 0x0102 then lower bytes (02) in this case gets saved in lower memory, but I'm not sure if this is the same for arrays.
Plus to make it multiplication of 4 are the bytes added to the end like I did or the opposite way?

No endianness only affects multi-byte entities.

@500-InternalServerError: An array is a multi-byte entity, generally.

Given that myID[x] is the same as *(myID + x) it should follow, regardless of the machine's endianness.

@David, 0x10b       | 0x00   ('\0'), 0x10a       | 0x00   ('\0') is not certain as myID[] has only 10 elements, not 12.

"Plus to make it multiplication of 4"… is irrelevant because the array element size is 1.

Array elements are always stored in the order of their indices.  Endianness is something that affects the bytes in an individual variable that is not an array or struct.
As as example, suppose you have the following:
uint16_t arr[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

On a little endian machine, the bytes of the array would be as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------
| 0x01 | 0x00 | 0x02 | 0x00 | 0x03 | 0x00 | 0x04 | 0x00 |
---------------------------------------------------------

While on a big endian machine, it would look like this:
---------------------------------------------------------
| 0x00 | 0x01 | 0x00 | 0x02 | 0x00 | 0x03 | 0x00 | 0x04 |
---------------------------------------------------------


Hi, just to make sure I understand what if I passed "2024" to int test(char* str) will it be treated as array or not?

@David A string literal is an array, and when you pass it to a function it gets converted to a pointer to its first element.

Thanks, where are the memory addresses in your answer? and can you please see my comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78618174/23344794 i guess there is a big contradiction

@David Addresses in the example are in increasing order.

why is that? that's a contradiction. stack is filled from higher addresses to lower addresses so if 1 is first element it gets filled in first free spot (by order) which means higher address...

@David Whether an array exists on the stack is irrelevant.  Array addresses always go from lower to higher addresses.  It wouldn't make sense for arrays to be stored one way on the stack and another way on the heap or in global data.

Elements of arrays are always stored in memory in order of array index. myID[0] is at the lowest memory address, myID[1] follows it, and so on.
Endianness is only relevant for scalar types, which are arithmetic (integer and floating-point types) and pointer types. For aggregate types (arrays and structures), the elements or members of the aggregate are always laid out in the order of their indices (for arrays) or their declaration (for structures).
Structures may have internal padding and/or trailing padding. Arrays do not have any padding between elements or after elements. (Each element itself may have padding, but this is a property of the element itself, not of the array.)

Great explanation but I think pair of examples of actual memory layout of single-byte element array (e.g. OPs example) and multi-byte element array would be beneficial.

Endianness only affects how multibyte scalar types are represented.  It does not affect array indexing or order of struct members.  Your array would look exactly the same on both big- and little-endian architectures.
Endianness would only affect the representation of individual array elements or struct members.
Given
struct s { int a; int b; } foo = { 0x01234567, 0x89abcdef };

you get something like this (addresses for illustration only):
Address    Member    LE    BE
-------    ------    --    --
0x1000          a    67    01
0x1001               45    23
0x1002               23    45
0x1003               01    67
0x1004          b    ef    89
0x1005               cd    ab
0x1006               ab    cd
0x1007               89    ef


can you kindly relate to my example

Stack grows from high to low addresses, so ur explanation means a should be in higher address as it's first element

@David -- note that the C Standard has nothing at all to say about stacks or heaps; these are not C language concepts, but rather implementation concepts.

@David: struct members are laid out in the order declared with increasing addresses, irrespective of stack behavior.

Endianness is a property of a processor that exists when the instruction set offers multi-byte reads from and writes to memory, e.g. movq, or lw (load word).
Since the hardware doesn't offer all possible sizes, then software still has to choose the order of bytes (or words/quads) in larger items (e.g. some 12-byte or some 128-bit data type).
If the hardware only offered reads and writes to memory as bytes, we would have to choose endianness in software — i.e. how to compose multiple bytes into a word, double, quad, etc..
In fact, software can still choose endianness opposite the hardware it is running on, and has to for example, when encoding/decoding TCP/IP packet headers on a little endian processor (since TCP/IP headers use network endian, which is big endian).  Otherwise, it would be silly for software to choose endianness that goes against what the hardware naturally does.
Software also chooses the order of fields in structures, and for C, there are strict rules so that C structures can interact with assembly and other languages.
While it would also be possible to store array elements backwards in memory or some other arrangement, the obvious choice of increasing index means increasing memory address is simple and often supported by an instruction set with indexing and scaling addressing modes.
Still, as hardware that provides scaling only offers certain limited sizes, arrays whose element size is not provided for (e.g. element size of 5, or of 128), then software does the scaling using multiplication and/or addition (and shifting, etc..).
Strings are arrays of bytes stored where each successive element (byte/character) is stored at successive (increasing) memory addresses, like other arrays — but since strings are arrays of bytes, there's no question of endianness, no question of ordering.
However, if you were to load a 32-bit word from the address of a string, "abcd", the numeric value in 32 bits would differ on a little vs. big endian processor.  But we typically don't look at word/double/quad sized numeric values from strings (we may use larger size to copy a string from one location in memory to another without really looking at the numeric values).

Hi, just to make sure I understand what if I passed "2024" to int test(char* str) will it be treated as array or not?

C barely has arrays.  Arrays are just some storage.  As soon as you use an array in an expression, it is immediately converted to a pointer, and we take it from there.  This instant and automatic conversion of array to pointer a lossy operation: once a pointer the language doesn't know how many elements are referred to by that pointer, whether one element or more than one.  So, when you write test ( "2024" ) the "2024" generates an initialized array of bytes in permanent program storage (like .rodata) and for the call to test the compiler passes the address of the first '2'.

So, yes it gets treated like any other array in C, which is to say it is immediately converted to pointer, and the callee, here test knows only the type of the item referred to by the pointer, but not the length, for example.  We could change test as follows int test ( char [] str ) but that only precludes test from modifying its formal parameter (i.e. str++ not allowed now) but this doesn't inform test any further than char *str would (e.g. there is still no array length information available for test).
